# How is a file loaded in the FAT file system?

Tags: filesystems, fat32, assembly

I am developing a bootloader in x86 Assembly and I have a question about the FAT file system.

Which steps are necessary to find and load the file?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is not exactly best practice. Are you sure you can't use an existing FAT32 driver?

Comment: @Daniel: I am studying the FAT file system for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple answer, so I won't delve into it here.
You have to peek into the FAT (File Allocation Table) structures on the disk:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system

More, Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table